# #1054 - Unknown column in 'group statement'

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this Sql query

```
SELECT tt.ID_Partenaire, tt.Nom_Societe,tt.Image_Societe, tt.id_activite 
                FROM affiliate AS a 
                RIGHT JOIN 
                  (SELECT p.ID_Partenaire, p.Nom_Societe, p.Image_Societe,p.id_activite,
                        IFNULL(SUM(c.montant_real),0) AS mt1 
                    FROM partenaires as p 
                        LEFT JOIN commande AS c 
                    ON p.ID_Partenaire=c.id_partenaire 
                    GROUP BY P.ID_Partenaire 
                  )AS tt 
            ON a.id_partenaire= tt.ID_Partenaire 
            GROUP BY tt.ID_Partenaire 
            ORDER BY (IFNULL(SUM(a.montat),0) + mt1) DESC 
            LIMIT 20
```

I have two server :

1. Version du serveur : 5.7.11-log - MySQL Community Server (GPL) -locally-
2. Server version: 10.1.25-MariaDB-1~jessie - mariadb.org binary distribution - host -

When i execute it on server1 it gives me a correct result but on server2 it gives me the error **#1054 - Unknown column 'P.ID_Partenaire' in 'group statement'**

---

the solution is the lower case P in group

---

I have another problem is that the results are not the same between the servers even that they have the same DB

Comment: Did you try to put p.ID_Partenaire instead of P.ID_Partenaire? Also, have in mind that the SQL commands vary a bit from a DBMS to another...

Comment: #1 (only) is on Windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the use of `p` as alias to `partenaires` table and the use of `P` (upper case) in the group statement (`P.ID_Partenaire`).

Try to standardize and not mix upper and lower case.

Also, have in mind that the SQL commands vary a bit from a DBMS to another...

Comment: I have another problem is that the results are not the same between the servers even that they have the same DB

Comment: I suggest you open another question, explaining better your problem and giving more details.